# Print All For Loop Array Values to Inner HTML

Tags: arrays, loops, printing, innerhtml

I would like to print some array values to the screen inside a container div.  The loop below is only printing the final array value "dog" to the screen.

I can't seem to work out the problem here?

JS

```
var arr = ["mouse", "cat", "dog"];
var holder = document.getElementById("holder");

for ( var i=0; i < arr.length; i+=1 ) {

holder.innerHTML = "<p>" + arr[i] + "</p><br/>" ;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: Append to innerHTML (`+=` not `=`) at the moment your overwriting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `+=` in `holder.innerHTML = "<p>" + arr[i] + "</p><br/>" ;`, otherwise it will overwrite the line for each iteration.

```js
var arr = ["mouse","cat","dog"];
var holder = document.getElementById("holder");
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
  holder.innerHTML += "<p>"+arr[i]+"</p><br>";
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```